# Razor variable into Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, razor

I am trying to set a JavaScript variable from a model variable using Razor, and can't figure out what is wrong.
In the CSHTML page, I've tried the following ways:

```
<script>
   var test1 = @Model.testVariable;
   var test2 = @(Model.testVariable);
   var test3 = <text>@Model.testVariable</text>
   var test4 = @Html.Raw(Model.testVariable);
</script>
```

In the Model, test variable is defined like

```
public string testVariable { get; set; }
```

In the controller, I am setting the variable like:

```
model.testVariable = "x";
```

Then when I access the variable, I almost always get the error `test1 is undefined`. If I set the variable like `var test1 = 'x'`, then it works fine. It is only having a problem when I am grabbing the variable from the model

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   alert(test1);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need to set a variable to a string literal, then it needs to be enclosed in quotes. For example:

```
<script>
   var test1 = '@Model.testVariable';
</script>
```

Comment: Yes, because otherwise JavaScript will interpret the value as a variable and try to access the variable with the identifier equal to the value of `@Model.testVariable`, which (in most cases) will be undefined.

Comment: @mhodges Or a syntax error if the string contains spaces or anything else that can be interpreted as code, it's actually quite dangerous.