# Convert razor c# string to jquery string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

when i use this code as script i get this error in console :

> Syntax Error: missing variable name

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var multiselect = $("#TahiyeKonande").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        var arr = [];
        var t = @ttt;
        var tt = t.split(",");
        console.log(tt);
        // set the value of the multiselect.
        console.log(arr);
        multiselect.value(arr);
    });
```

Comment: `var t = '@ttt';`

Comment: Possible duplicates of [Razor variable into Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45285302/razor-variable-into-javascript) and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14866539/how-to-set-javascript-variables-using-mvc4-with-razor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for convert razor viewbag string to js use double quotation

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var multiselect = $("#TahiyeKonande").data("kendoMultiSelect");
        var arr = [];
        var t = "@ttt";
        var tt = t.split(",");
        console.log(tt);
        // set the value of the multiselect.
        console.log(arr);
        multiselect.value(arr);
    });
```

Comment: tanks bro it worked